# Removing JPanel from a JFrame in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have several JPanels that contain buttons, labels, etc. that I want to switch between from a main JFrame. Currently I am trying to use the  `this.add(JPanelname);` method and `this.remove(JPanelname);` with the `validate();` and `repaint();` methods

The problem is it will add the panel to the `JFrame` but it will not remove it. I am not sure how exactly to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should be using a [Card Layout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Or maybe you should be using modal JDialogs. So whenever you click on the "widjet" a new window is displayed. Then when you close the dialog you are back on your main frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you are constantly switching between JPanels, then a [JTabbedPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) may be the right thing to use. It should not be necessary to call "validate" or "repaint" when you add or remove a JPanel. Do you have a layout manager installed? Do you make sure to call add/remove only within the UI event thread? Also, typically one does not call "validate()" but rather "invalidate()" to invalidate the container for updates.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! A JTabbedPane is not exactly the look I was going for, I should have described it a little more thoroughly. I have a main pane that works as a sort of desktop i guess you could call it where the buttons are like widgets that when clicked will load separate parts of the program(IE a setup screen)  and then when the user is finished they can hit a back button and then the panel will close (possibly be removed from the frame and then the frame repainted?) and the main screen will be shown again. I may be going about this the wrong way hope this makes it more clear